# Custom Create page with Drawer but can not display <AutocompleteInput/>

Tags: react-admin

when i custom my Create page using  ,the  can not display correctly. how to fix it?
you can see the following reproduce in code-sandbox.
Visit [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-admin-advanced-recipes-createedit-from-list-mnfch)

> 1. enter the tags list
> 2. click the create button, enter to the Create page.
> 3. see the input of post.

```
<Create title=" " {...props}>
       <SimpleForm toolbar={<TagCreateToolbar onCancel={onCancel} 
 />}>
           <TextInput source="name" validate={required()} />
           <ReferenceInput label="Post" source="post_id" reference="posts">
               <AutocompleteInput optionText="title" />
           </ReferenceInput>
       </SimpleForm>
   </Create>
```

Comment: i know is cause of z-index  of Drawer is too big.but how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the file: src/tags/index.js as follows:

```
import TagList from './TagList';
import TagCreate from './TagCreate';
import TagEdit from './TagEdit';

export default {
    list: TagList,
    create: TagCreate,
    edit: TagEdit
};
```

It's still worth updating react-admin before the last release of 2.9.6